# No adapter attached; skipping layout and org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android

Here am using JSON and volley library to fetch data from MYSQL sever(WAMP).
How do I pass the row ID (MYSQL) of a list to another activity, like when the user clicks, it will fetch the data from server and show it in another activity?I've spent 2 days to find a solution with of problem.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {

                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Product product1=new Product();

                            product1.setName(product.getString("name"));
                            product1.setDescription(product.getString("description"));
                            productList.add(product1);

                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setuprecyclerview(productList);
                    }

                    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
} private void setuprecyclerview(List<Product> productList) {
    myadapter = new ProductAdapter(this,productList) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
}
```

Here is PHP statement

> $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT
>   domainname.name,domaindecription.description FROM(
>   domainname,domaindescription WHERE domainname.id=
>   domaindesriptionc.id_fk");

Answer (score 0):

So you want above data item ID to pass in Another Activity
In above code first add `ID` also in productHolder while parsing
Now in RecycleView in 
`onBindHolder()` put a click on item
Then in that click

```
Intent in=new Intnet(context,MyActivity.class);
in.putExtra("id",productList.get(position).getId());
startActivity(in);

MyActivity.java
```

In `onCreate()`
String id=null;

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
if(intent!=null)
{
id=intent.getStringExtra("id");
getDataFromAPIWithID(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the Edited code-Hope it will usefull for others.public void loadDomainId(int domainid) {

```
    String url = Constants.URL_DOMAINS_DETAILS + "?&domainid=" + domainid;
    Log.d("DETAIL", "URL: " + url);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("DETAIL", "RESPONSE: " + response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Description product1 = new Description();
                            product1.setId(product.getInt("id"));
                            product1.setName(product.getString("description"));
                            descriptionList.add(product1);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    displayDomain(descriptionList);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }) {


    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);

}
```